# How to parse DateTime in this format? “Tue Dec 22 19:16:57 2015 UTC”

Tags: java, datetime, date-format, simpledateformat

I wanna parse a date that comes in this format "Tue Dec 22 19:16:57 2015 UTC"  in java
Is this a valid UTC DateTime? And how to parse it? I tried :

```
 DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy UTC");
```

Comment: With respect (to the number of times this type of question gets asked), you get out the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and check the available specifications, you do some research into what other people have done and you try a number of approaches, if you really think you can't find the answer, which happens, you let use know what else you've tried (and *"I've tried everything"* isn't what we want to hear, maybe show use the formats you've tried, for example)

Answer (score 1):

Consulting the [`SimpleDateFormat` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), we see that:

- The format specifier for the name of the weekday is `E`, not `d`
- The format specifier for a timezone indicator (UTC being a timezone indicator of sorts) is `Z` for RFC-822 timezones (or `X` for ISO-8601 timezones, or `z` for "general" timezones)

So the string is `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Z"`. [Live Example on IDEone](http://ideone.com/JQ3jQH)

However, the documentation doesn't say that `UTC` will be recognized as a timezone (either with `Z` or `X` or `z`), so you may want to pre-process the string to change `UTC` to one of the specifiers supported by [RFC-822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt):

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Z");
String s = "Tue Dec 22 19:16:57 2015 UTC";
s = s.replace("UTC", "GMT");
Date d = format.parse(s);
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/AZuLxy)

If your locale isn't English by default, you'll also need to tell `SimpleDateFormat` to use English (since those are English day and month names):

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: it gives an exception ;  ** Unparseable date: "Tue Dec 22 19:16:57 2015 GMT" **

Comment: @AhmetOğruz: No, it doesn't -- see the live examples.

Comment: @AhmetOğruz Concur with TJ, it works and `System.out.println(d);` prints `Wed Dec 23 06:16:57 EST 2015`  for me

Comment: [link] http://oi67.tinypic.com/j67k08.jpg

Comment: I upadted as below and it works,

  DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Z",Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: @AhmetOğruz: Well of course. If your locale isn't English (which you didn't mention), how would you expect `SimpleDateFormat` to parse English day and month names?! I've added that information to the answer, but the answer was correct in the first place based on the information actually in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Always refer to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for additional information.

```
 DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy Z");
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you have your code written, but one way to display it in Military time, you could do this:

return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, minute, second); //The first argument being key. and the second argument being what is going to be displayed in each "%02d"
Will be displayed as 00:00:00

Hope this helps. :-)